# [ROS2 Foxy] Setting log level in launch file

Tags: ros2, roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`Node( package='nav2_planner', executable='planner_server', name='planner_server', output='screen', parameters=[configured_params], remappings=remappings),`

How would you set the debug log level here?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/363625/%5Bros2-foxy%5D-setting-log-level-in-launch-file/) by [avzmpy](https://answers.ros.org/users/56476/avzmpy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2020-10-17

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can add an **arguments** section to your Node, where you can specify a log level. It'll be look like:

```
Node(
    # (...)
    arguments=['--ros-args', '--log-level', 'DEBUG']
)
```

---

Originally posted by [abrzozowski](https://answers.ros.org/users/28240/abrzozowski/) with karma: 290 on 2020-10-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5